# Python numpy sum along axis error

Tags: python, numpy, sum

```
def tfdif(docs,normalize)
    docs_tokens = {idx: get_doc_tokens(doc, normalize) for idx, doc in enumerate(docs)}
    dtm = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(docs_tokens, orient="index")
    dtm = dtm.fillna(0)
    tf = dtm.values
    **doc_len = tf.sum(axis=1)**
tfidf(docs, 'stem')
```

**I get this error which i am unable to figure out

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Atiq/Documents/CS/BIA 660/Assignment 5/Assignment 5.py", line 91, in <module>
>       tfidf(docs, 'stem')
>     File "C:/Users/Atiq/Documents/CS/BIA 660/Assignment 5/Assignment 5.py", line 51, in tfidf
>       doc_len = tf.sum(axis=1)
>     File "C:\Users\Atiq\PycharmProjects\Trail\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core_methods.py", line 32, in _sum
>       return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
>   TypeError: must be str, not int**

Comment: Please post a _minimal_ working example, not the whole code body.

Comment: I did that @DyZ but I did not get any response waited for days so i reposted with the full code. I am uanble to figure it out where the problem lies so.

Comment: This strategy is not helpful. What makes you think we will answer a question that does not follow the posting guidelines?

Comment: I apologize but I am a beginner. Ill do it right away

Comment: Please include a small sample of `tf` (e.g., `head(tf)`).

Comment: Could it be because of the `dtm.fillna(0)`?

Comment: @DyZ  for stem['instead' '30' 'late' ... 0 0 0]
 ['play' "n't" 'glad' ... 0 0 0]
 ['know' 'set' 'wayn' ... 0 0 0]]

Comment: So, you have a mix of strings and numbers. They cannot be added up. See Jon's comment above.

Comment: @Jon no jon i pass two functions 1. tfidf(docs, None) which works perfectly and another one tfidf(docs, 'stem') which gives me this error